# Unstacking MS Excel data in columns to rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a small challenge at hand and have I tried pivot table, and the help of Google to do this activity. But I have seen the solutions for very structured/organized data in a pattern. The challenge I have is given below.

Data in table 1, consisting of 2 columns. Column 1 "part no." and column 2 is corresponding "supplier part no." A given part no. in column 1 could have multiple supplier part nos. in column 2 as they are supplied by different suppliers (each supplier will have their own part no. naming convention).

What I would like to do is, for a part no. of ours would like to have all the corresponding supplier part nos. in the same row in different columns (basically unstacking it?)

Please see the attachments for better clarity.

Unstacking challenge explained:

[image: Unstacking challenge explained_Updated]

Data table:

[image: Data table]

It would be great if someone could provide me guidance!

| Part No. | Supplier Part No. | Supplier Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC12345 | AB36062653 | Supplier no. 1 |
| FGHHJK8765 | 4-514903600 | Supplier no. 1 |
| HGD5 | 196032821-03 | Supplier no. 1 |
| GHJJ677 | 430662322-AA | Supplier no. 1 |
| SDFG3456 | 01-103622307 | Supplier no. 1 |
| ABC12345 | 38707105_01 | Supplier no. 2 |
| DFG4567 | ab403649756 | Supplier no. 2 |
| GHJJ677 | 7R-412929801 | Supplier no. 2 |
| HGD5 | 00-357031751 | Supplier no. 2 |
| SDFG3456 | 509806089-4A | Supplier no. 2 |
| SDFG3456 | TYR488316651 | Supplier no. 3 |
| HGD5 | 99804219BJK | Supplier no. 3 |
| DFG4567 | 389816712jk | Supplier no. 3 |
| ABC12345 | CB361990766 | Supplier no. 3 |
| ABC12345 | RRR519537923BB | Supplier no. 4 |
| ABC12345 | FNKG485505159 | Supplier no. 5 |
| DFG4567 | BB16633987UUU | Supplier no. 4 |
| DFG4567 | 204272737GH_01 | Supplier no. 5 |
| FGHHJK8765 | E168552849K | Supplier no. 4 |
| FGHHJK8765 | gh_01_124784471 | Supplier no. 5 |
| SDFG3456 | 65610572JFJD | Supplier no. 5 |
| HGD5 | 214258608KMCFK | Supplier no. 4 |
| GHJJ677 | YTUYJ372430994 | Supplier no. 4 |
| GHJJ677 | HDJSFHDJ-524930743 | Supplier no. 5 |

Comment: What is the logic behind which columns are blank int he result?

Comment: @AlexisOlson That means supplier No. 1 doesn't supply our part no. DFG4567. Hence he hasn't got a corresponding part no.

Comment: How do you map the part number to the supplier? I don't see a supplier column. If you did have a supplier column, then this would just be a pivot.

Comment: I have updated my challenge picture now. I know in the value field of pivot-table we can have data in number. I am unsure how to get the alphanumeric with special characters displayed as shown in table 2.

Comment: Supplying your data table as text would make things much simpler for those trying to help you.

Comment: Have now made an attempt to provide the data table in text

Comment: Looks like all you need is a simple Pivot table (in PQ) with no aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped and learnt something new, and perfectly answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data setup, in Power Query this is a simple Pivot operation with no aggregation.

**M Code**
*change table name in line 2 to your real table name*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8_2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Part No.", type text}, {"Supplier Part No.", type text}, {"Supplier Name", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[#"Supplier Name"]),
             "Supplier Name", "Supplier Part No.")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

The results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In versions of Excel that support Dynamic Array formula, you can use this

Cell `H7`

```
=YourTableName[[#Headers],[Part No.]]
```

Cell `H8`

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(YourTableName[Part No.]))
```

Cell `I7`

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(YourTableName[Supplier Name]))))
```

CellI8

```
=XLOOKUP(H8#&"_"&I7#,YourTableName[Part No.]&"_"&YourTableName[Supplier Name],YourTableName[Supplier Part No.],"",0,1)`
```

[image]